# I am getting unexpected output in this Program

Tags: c

I just want to replace specific character from file.
for example, I want to replace character 'l' with character 'p'.
is it correct way ?

```
int main() {
  FILE * ptr;
  ptr = fopen("D:\f4.txt", "r+");

  if (ptr == NULL) {
    printf("file cant be opened");
    exit(0);
  }

  char ch = fgetc(ptr);
  while (ch != EOF) {
    if (ch == 'l') {
      fseek(ptr, -1, 1);
      fputc('p', ptr);
    }

    ch = fgetc(ptr);
  }

  fclose(ptr);
}
```

suppose content in my file is "hello everyone" so output should be like "heppo everyone" but it writes in file "hepepepepepepepepepepepepepepep" continuesly. please help me to find why this happen.

Comment: Now, format the rest of the code yourself...

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks, I am posting first time so that's why I don't know exactly. it's just suggested by StackOverflow and I just did it accordingly. but btw thanks and please help me.

Comment: The reason for the infinite loop is that fgetc() returns an int, not char. The value EOF is different from any char, so you'll never see it. Also, what's the fseek() there for? I see no reason for it at all.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker so can you suggest me that what could be the code for this problem. ?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker the `fseek` is there so that the `'l'` can be overwritten with a `'p'`.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker  i want to overwrite l with p/

Answer (score 1):

Please note this from the [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2017) for `fopen()`.

> When the **"r+"**, **"w+"**, or **"a+"** access type is specified, both reading and writing are enabled (the file is said to be open for "update"). However, when you switch from reading to writing, the input operation must encounter an EOF marker. If there is no EOF, you must use an intervening call to a file positioning function. The file positioning functions are `fsetpos`, `fseek`, and `rewind`. *When you switch from writing to reading, you must use an intervening call to either `fflush` or to a file positioning function.* (my italics)

So after you wrote `'p'` to the file, it is not enough to carry on reading as though nothing has happened, you must `fseek` to the original position, obtained by `ftell`, or `fflush` the file.

Also don't use magic numbers: in `fseek` you should use `SEEK_CUR` not `1`.

Finally, function `fgetc` returns an `int` type, not `char`. This allows `EOF` to be distinguished from the data byte `0xFF`.

Comment: can you please please explain me little bit more.. because i am new to c. i know how to use fflush(). but why i have to use fflush here , I am not getting.

Comment: The man page explains that you have to: *When you switch from writing to reading, you must use an intervening call to either fflush or to a file positioning function.*

Comment: but i am using fseek() here. it says use either fflush or(fseek(),fsetpos,rewind). so instead of using fflush i used fseek().

Comment: That is between the read and the write. You must deal with changing from write to read too, as the man page says. After the `fputc`.

Comment: It's what the C standard says. What happens under the hood is the busines of the implementation.